# Different layout behavior in desktop and tablet or smartphone

Tags: html, css, layout, responsiveness

I have a problem with a Website that I am building:

The design works perfectly on any device, especially on tablets and smartphones. It also works perfectly in Chrome Developer Tools -devices simulator.

[image]

However, when I reduce the size of the screen in a desktop to a similar size of a tablet or smartphone the design looks broken. The text is not respecting the z-index and it is visible over the active menu.

[image]

What could be the problem? Does anybody have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

use class of bootstrap for multiple layout
If u use mobile use class of class="col-sm-12" etc.

Comment: And what does it has to do with the z-index? How is it related to the problem shown in the images?

Answer (score 0):

If you reload the page after you resize it on a desktop screen, is the design still broken?

Comment: If I reload the page, the menu is closed and I have to open it, by pressing the "hamburger". Ending in the same position.
The unfolded menu does not respect the z-index and it is not possible to click on the menu items.

Comment: From the first picture it doesn't seem there is z-index involved. It looks like the menu is pushing the content down and not covering it with a higher z-index to come in front of it.

Comment: The problem is probably the height of the opened menu.

Comment: But what I do not understand is why there is different behaviours. Either pushing the content down or covering it. Is just the same code!